# How to customize PayPal button using script?

Tags: html, paypal

I am new with PayPal integration and setting and trying to customize the PayPal button in the below script.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb"> // Required. Replace SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID.
</script>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            color: 'gold',
            shape: 'pill',
            label: 'paypal'
        },
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '0.01'
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

In their document, there is a PayPal icon before texting in the button which I am not getting so can you please guide me why I am not getting it.

Output of above code

[image]

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/#layout

Comment: Yes, because they remove the icon of first button, you can check in example site. https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
and if you want to change icon or customize more you can do by using css.

Answer (score 0):

> In their document, there is a PayPal icon before texting in the button which I am not getting so can you please guide me why I am not getting it.

The document is out of date. The first button (PayPal) no longer includes a logo as of several months ago.

You are seeing the current and correct behavior.